# why does this code gives stackoverflow error when word length is beyond 4?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, stack-overflow

i have written a code to generate all possible combinations of letters of a word without any repetition of any letter or any particular word. the code is as follows

```
static boolean redcheck(int array[])// checks if letters are repeated
{
    boolean check=true;
    for(int i=0;i<array.length-1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<array.length;j++)
        {
            if(array[i]==array[j])
            {
                check=false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return check;
}

static void repeat(char arr2[],int arr1[],int p)// creates and prints the word
{
    if(redcheck(arr1))
    {
        for(int i=0;i<p;i++)
            System.out.print(arr2[arr1[i]]);
        for(int i=0;i<p;i++)
            System.out.print(arr1[i]);
        System.out.println();
    }
    arr1[p-1]+=1;
    for(int ini=p-1;ini>0;ini--)
    {  
        if(arr1[ini]>p-1)
        {
            arr1[ini-1]+=1;
            arr1[ini]=0;  
        }
    }
    if(arr1[0]>p-1)
        return;

    repeat(arr2,arr1,p);
}

public static void main()
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter word");
    String a=sc.nextLine();
    int num=a.length();
    char arr[]=new char[num];
    for(int c=0;c<a.length();c++)
        arr[c]=a.charAt(c);

    int arr1[]=new int[num];
    for(int i:arr1)
        arr1[i]=0;
    repeat(arr,arr1,num);

}
```

the code works fine till any word of upto length 4, but when its above four, it throws up a stack overflow error. after some inspection, the main part of code which is creating the problem is the printing part itself, which is

```
for(int i=0;i<p;i++)
            System.out.print(arr2[arr1[i]]);
```

i really cant find where i am going wrong. the print statement below the one mentioned above, prints the indexes of the words in order which they will be printed and does not give any error. 
i am using the bluej editor, and it seems i have 512MB in stack memory.
please help.thanks in advance.

EDIT:  the error code is 
       java.lang.StackOverflowError:
       null

Comment: It's not clear to me how the code is meant to work, but you're always recursing unless `arr1[0] > p - 1`. Did you mean to recurse that much? Note that you could easily avoid recursion just by using a do/while loop instead.

Comment: Including the exact error message would help

Comment: @JonSkeet the way the letters are rearranged can be compared to those click counters gatekeeping people use. suppose you have a number system which only has the numbers 0,1,2. now the smallest is 000, then you increment one to get 001, then 002. when 002 comes, the next number should normally have been 003, but 3 is not included, thus the units place is reset and the next place is incremented by 1.giving 010. like that the last should be 222, and thus when its incremented by one, the logic leads to 300 being made, but as 3 is not included and is in the last place, so the function is terminated

Comment: @P.Soutzikevich its java.lang.StackOverflowError: null

Comment: @Crasshassin Not in the comments. Edit your question appropriately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With 4 letters (assuming none of them are the same) there are 4^4 = 256 possible combinations of these letters. As your code is currently set up, you will recurse at least 256 times before returning a value which will have a big memory cost on your stack. If you try to scale up to 5 letters (once again assuming none are the same) you will have 5^5 = 3125 possible combinations, etc...
The stack overflow error you get is due to the amount of time you recurse.

My recommendation:
separate your repeat method into two parts:

```java
static void printWord(char arr2[],int arr1[],int p) {
    if(redcheck(arr1))
    {
        for(int i=0;i<p;i++)
            System.out.print(arr2[arr1[i]]);
        for(int i=0;i<p;i++)
            System.out.print(arr1[i]);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

and then your repeat method:

```java
static void repeat(char arr2[],int arr1[],int p)// creates and prints the word
{
    while(arr1[0] < p-1){
        printWord(char arr2[],int arr1[],int p);
        arr1[p-1]+=1; // your looping logic
        for(int ini=p-1;ini>0;ini--)
        {  
            if(arr1[ini]>p-1)
            {
                arr1[ini-1]+=1;
                arr1[ini]=0;  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

making it non recursive will help you avoid the stack overflow error.

Additional recommendations:
Verify if the input word does not have two of the same letters before running any logic, your code will not find any combinations if I input the word "see" as there are no combinations such that a three letter word can be created with the letters {'s','e','e'} without any of them repeating. 
Your `redcheck` method uses one too many variables:

```java
static boolean redcheck(int array[])// checks if letters are repeated
{
    for(int i=0;i<array.length-1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<array.length;j++)
        {
            if(array[i]==array[j])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: thank you @michmich12. let me be true here, i really had thought about dividing the program into parts, and had left the idea as i thought it to be trivial. but you know what, this actually helped. the code can now handle 5 letter words, but guess what, it cannot do 6 letter ones. it seems the problem is with the memory as you pointed out, but now, the code cant be divided any further, so it seems 5 is the limit now!. but still, thank you very much for the answer!!

Comment: No problem @Crasshassin. What sort of error is returned with 6 letters?

Comment: @michmich12, and as for the redcheck method, and recurring letters , yes the program can handle them nicely(yes with the caveat of only 5 letter words!), because you see , the letters in the word are not being used directly, the other array actually makes every letter unique, as they have individual indexes of numerical format. the red(dundancy)check method compares this indices and not the letters itself, so the recurring letters pose no problem as far as logic is concerned, but still that memory problem will keep bugging me!

Comment: the 6 letter one gives the same error as the five letter was giving, i.e java.lang.StackOverflowError: null

Comment: @Crasshassin I see what you were going fo now. Thanks for explaining. I'll try to look into the memory problem and see if i can get the full stack trace

Comment: @michmich12 thanks ! . by the way, i just tried to change the stack size, but it seems it had no effect.  while you continue to look for an answer to the memeory problem, i will keep trying to find out if by anyway i can restrict or splice up each word into 5 letter or less words.Thanks again!

Comment: @michmich12 , i forgot about a thing.i had developed this code from another code of mine, which uses the same logic but has a different purpose. that code creates binary sequences of any number of digits. the sequence here means an ascending sequence like this. if the user enters 3, it will print 000,001,010,011,100,101,110,111. and similarly for any number. after the code in this question started bugging me, i tried testing this binary code. and it seems the limit for this is 12 digits. this is going into a very mysteriously interesting direction!